# Отсортировать список чисел Python

Tags: python, сортировка, list

Список `list [.,.,.,.,]` чисел.
Как отсортировать?
`sorted_list=sorted(list.key=operator.itemgetter)` не работает

Comment: Вот здесь `sorted_list=sorted(list.key=operator.itemgetter)` между list и key должна быть запятая, а не точка. И если у вас просто список чисел, то достаточно просто `sorted_list=sorted(list)`.

Comment: Читайте [документацию](https://docs.python.org)

Answer (score 5):

Т.к. импортирован модуль `random` ответ может отличаться.

```
import random
g = []
for i in range(10):
    g.append(random.randrange(1, 1000))
g.sort()
print(g)
# [55, 248, 352, 371, 398, 574, 764, 772, 802, 902]
```

---

Пример без модуля `random`

```
g = [2, 478, 5, 834, 1]
g.sort()
print(g)
# [1, 2, 5, 478, 834]
```

Про использование функции `sort` можете почитать [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort)